# UpshotContext handle post

Tags: asp.net-mvc, upshot

Can't find any documentation for **DataController** and **UpshotContext** combination.
I see Upshot calls "**Submit**" method on DataController (inherite from base) and than using naming convention **Insert**, **Delete** or **Update** method is called.

How to explicitly set name of the datacontroller method to call when doing post with **this.dataSource.commitChanges()** (or any other action) ?